# if with AND Operator in java

Tags: java

I have a block of code which uses if statement with AND operator:

```
final String NODE_TYPE_LIST = "List";
final String NODE_TYPE_DETAIL = "Detail";
if ((!NODE_TYPE_LIST.equalsIgnoreCase(dataNodeBean.getType())) 
                    && (!NODE_TYPE_DETAIL.equalsIgnoreCase(dataNodeBean.getType()))) {
                throw new InvalidNodeTypeException("Invalid Node type.");
            }
```

For exampled, if dataNodeBean.getType() returns "List".
According to [this](http://www.dummies.com/programming/java/and-operators-and-in-java/) link, above code should throw InvalidNodeTypeException only if both expressions in if statement returns true. But when i'm debugging the program( where dataNodeBean.getType() returns "List" ) i see both expressions being evaluated even though the first expression returns false, as a result the InvalidNodeTypeException(Custom Exception) is thrown.
What i expect from this code is to throw an exception when the dataNodeBean.getType() doesn't returns either List or Detail.
I don't understand what i'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Are you sure that `getType` returns `String` and not some other object?

Comment: @npinti yes getType returns String.

Comment: @KrutiPatel this leads to pseudocode `value != aString OR value != anotherString` which is always `true` because `value` cannot be equal to both strings

Comment: why i have got a down vote?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine. I ran the following test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(test("A"));
    System.out.println(test("B"));
    System.out.println(test("C"));
}

private static boolean test(String value) {
    return (!"a".equalsIgnoreCase(value)) && (!"b".equalsIgnoreCase(value));
}
```

And it returned

```
false
false
true
```

Just as you'd expect. I suspect the issue is in the `getType` method. An easy way to confirm is to move your check to a separate method that is passed the result of `getType` and then write some unit test confirming that it returns true for anything other than "list" or "detail".